# can I send JavaScript Data from PHP to Html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to send from PHP, data that can be retrieved with jQuery **data** function?
I know how to sent properties and attributes, but I want to send data objects.

In other words, how should I render a div to get data with jQuery?

```
<div id="div" <!-- Whet should I put here??-->></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on where you wrote the data in the div i figure that you want to use the attributes on your div

like this :

```
<div id="my_div" data-my-attribue="value"></div>
```

Then you can get this value in jQuery typing this

```
$('#my_div').attr('data-my-attribue');
```

(This is valid in html 5)

Comment: you can also use jQuery's .data() method directly: $('#my_div').data('my-attribute');

Comment: @Clement yes i looked at the other answer and i just saw that, i learned something new :) Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. But why write it in div? Encode PHP object as JSON and just print it directly into JavaScript inside `<script>` tag.

Comment: Many tags on the page come accross Ajax, I can't do it

Comment: Yes, you can. If you just appending incoming data to DOM, there's really no difference in appending either `div` or `script` tags. And sending JSON will provide even cleaner way with parsing response with `JSON.parse` without any additional HTML markup or quoting.

Comment: I mean, each element have it's own related data, would be very annoying to map javaScript variables to the corresponding element.. Isn't way easier to use $('element').data('someId')?....

Comment: Well, this could be a personal preference, but I personally really hate to store data in visual layer (HTML). I generally store all data in JS and build DOM from it. When I'd need to instrument outside HTML with additional data, I'd still keep it in JS, inside object with keys being unique IDs and values - free form data. This way I'd only have to put those same unique IDs on HTML elements, while still keeping everything else in JS.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<div id="unique-id" data-hello="<?php echo "world" ?>"></div>

alert($('#unique-id').data('hello')); // world
```

Check out: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

You can also:

```
var php_data = <?php json_encode(array('hello', 'world')); ?>;

alert(php_data); // hello,world
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

```
<div id="div" data-test="test1"></div>
alert($('#div').data('test'));// will show 'test1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myId" data-nameitwhateveryoulike="add your data here">Blah blah</div>
```

You can name data attributes whatever you like, you just have to precede it with "data-", as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input type hidden field to send and retrieve datas from php , though the best practice is to use ajax.

```
<input type='hidden' value='myvalue' id='mykey'/>

<script>
 var mykey = document.getElementById("mykey").value;
</script>
```